# ros noetic installation problem on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ros

i just want to install Ros Noetic on my virtual machine (ubuntu)
and im following this source (http://wiki.ros.org/noetic/Installation/Ubuntu) LINE BY LINE

but when i do these command = (sudo apt update)
i just get these errors
[image]

Err:7 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu jammy Release
404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

i don't know what to do

please help me to fix this problem

Answer (score 0):

Jammy is the Ubuntu 22.04 release. However, Noetic only targets 20.04. There are also currently no ROS1 distros that target above 20.04.

You need to either downgrade your VM to 20.04, or you can install a [ROS2 distro that supports 22.04](https://docs.ros.org/en/rolling/Releases/Release-Humble-Hawksbill.html)